# bind listview with list of model class in xaml (win8)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, windows-8

I am working on metro app c#/xaml, I want to bind listview with webservice function which returns  `List<delNewsletter>`

where  **delNewsletter** is class

`public class delNewsletter
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string name { set; get; }
  }`

and I am binding like this :

`lstNews.ItemsSource= await client.GetDeletedNewslettersAsync("token", 1, 2);`

but listview item showing content like this 
`test.win8.delNewsletter` this is method path.

how i can bind listview?

Comment: You want to display name or both id and name? Can you post XAML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `DisplayMemberPath` to listView otherwise it will simply call `ToString()` on your object and will show class name which it is showing right now.

You can specify it either in code behind or in XAML -

```
lstNews.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
```

OR

```
<ListView DisplayMemberPath="{Binding name}"/>
```

But in case you want to show both Id and name in your listView, you need to provide template to your listView -

```
     <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try to override `ToString` method of your delNewsletter class.
to something like that:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Name: {0}, Id: {1}", Name, Id);
}
```

Comment: hmm... just for experiment... 
what will you see in case of =await client.GetDeletedNewslettersAsync("token", 1, 2).Select(d => d.Name);